# Table Layout not refreshing properly - Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am developing an android application where I need the table to refresh when an event occurs. That is when a user clicks on a button, the table should now change displaying new data. So I used removeAllViews for this purpose. I will then add the rows to the table dynamically. What is happening is, when the number of rows are less than the previous number of rows, then the new rows are displayed and below them , old rows are also displayed. Can you please tell me what needs to be done.

```
TableLayout tableLayout1;                                     
public void displayPanel1(int co)    // dynamically add table
{    
   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.asdf);
   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            
   for(int i=0;i<co;i++) {
       TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);     
       for(int j=0;j<12;j++) {
           TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
           tv2.setText(i+j+""+"\n"+"h");
           tR.addView(tv2);           
       }
       tableLayout1.addView(tR);       
    }
    ll.addView(tableLayout1, lp);        
}
```

In the click event I have written  tableLayout1.removeAllViews(); and callecalled displayPanel() function again

Comment: Can you please show us some relevant code? Without seeing what you are doing we can only guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Are you using any theme ?? Try invalidating your layout as well.

Comment: I am not using any theme. I tried invalidating too.. but it doesn't work still :(

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

The lay out was given worngly. On changing the layout, it was getting refreshed properly. I changed the lay out to 
TableLayout.LayoutParams parms = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tableLayout1.setLayoutParams(parms);